# Proving Equality About The Null Space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

let there be a matrix $A^{n*m}$ that $Ax=b$

the solution set of the homogeneous system  $H=(h\in F^m; Ah=0)$ 

the solution set of the non-homogeneous system $L=(l \in F^m; Al=b)$

Prove: if $l_0\in L $ then $H=L-l_0$

So what I did is $A(L-l_0)=AL-Al_0=b-b=0$

Have I prove $H=L-l_0$ or $L-l_0 \in H$ ?

Comment: Be careful, applying matrices (or linear maps) to sets as in $AL$ is not properly allowed in linear algebra. You can give a meaning to it (typically the set of all values obtained by selecting vectors from the set) but then not all manipulations allowed for proper expression are automatically allowed for these new expressions. In any case you would get $A(L-l_0)=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to be a bit careful with the notation, although everything seems to work out ok - for example, it doesn't really make sense to write $AL=b$, because $A$ is matrix and $L$ is a set, but what is true is that $Al=b$ for all $l\in L$. However, what you have done is perfectly reasonable short-hand, providing you are confident you aren't hiding mistakes in it, which in this case you aren't.

What you have proved is that $l-l_0\in H$ for all $l\in L$. (If you let $L-l_0=\{l-l_0:l\in L\}$, which presumably you do, then you could write this as $L-l_0\subseteq H$).

You haven't proved the equality - given $h\in H$, how do you know it is of the form $l-l_0$ for some $l\in L$?

Comment: $Ah=A(L-l_0)=AL-Al_0=b-b=0$
Therefore: $H\subseteq L-l_0$ ?

Comment: No - your very first equality assumes $h\in L-l_0$, which is exactly what you are trying to prove. See Sami's answer; the principle is that you have some $h$ satisfying $Ah=b$, and you want to write $h=l-l_0$ for some $l$ satisfying $Al=0$. So you write down an $l$; it *has* to be $l=h+l_0$, because that's the only $l$ satisfying $h=l-l_0$, so now you have to hope that $Al=0$...

Answer (score 2):

No by your work you just proved that

$$L-l_0\subset H$$
Now for the converse, let $h\in H$ then 
$$A(h+l_0)=Ah+Al_0=b\implies h+l_0\in L$$
so 
$$H+l_0\subset L\iff H\subset L-l_0$$
and the result follows from the double inclusion.